# How to unquote function argument in rlang

Tags: r, rlang

I have two lists to combine:

```
x <- list(id1 = list(q1 = list(a = 5, b = 8), q7 = list(c = "a", d = "e")),
  id2 = list(q1 = list(a = 6, b = 4), q8 = list(k = "t", w = 5)))

y <- list(q1 = list(v = 6, t = 7.6), q9 = list(n = 6, m = 7.6))
```

I need to get list z:

```
z <- purrr::map(x, function(data) {
    data[names(data) %in% names(y)] <-
      purrr::list_merge(data[names(data) %in% names(y)],
        !!!y[names(y) %in% names(data)])
    data})
```

When I try to write general function for this using rlang's enqous and !!!, for example:

```
  list_smart_merge <- function(list1, list2) {
    list3 <- rlang::enquos(list2[q_names %in% names(data)])
    purrr::map(list1, function(data) {
      data[names(data) %in% names(list2)] <-
        purrr::list_merge(data[names(data) %in% names(list2)],
      !!list3)
      data})}
```

I get errors like "Inputs to capture must be argument names". Could someone explain me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So how are you calling this `list_smart_merge` function? What are you passing in, just `x` and `y`? I don't see why you would need quoting/unquoting for that. You could just but the same code you used for `z` inside a function with parameters `x` and `y`.

Comment: `list_smart_merge(x, y)`
Error: Inputs to capture must be argument names

Comment: Can't you just do `list_smart_merge <- function(x, y) { purrr::map(x, function(data) {data[names(data) %in% names(y)] <- purrr::list_merge(data[names(data) %in% names(y)], !!!y[names(y) %in% names(data)]); data})}`. I'm not sure why you're trying to `enquo` here. That's most use useful when you are trying to specify a column name inside a data.frame or tibble.

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick! It works.